# Spring Boot Multi Module used with Micro Services and Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm converting all our old monolithic applications into shared micro services using spring boot. To help maintain all the applications I'd like to use a single gradle file located in the root of the parent directory. I stumbled on the spring boot multi module project https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ and started down that path.

My question is can the multi module project be used to share a single parent gradle file as well as shared libraries and still be able to produce individual jars for each micro service? I get the impression when using multi modules only a single jar will be produced and all the modules will be a part of that single jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have few points.

> I get the impression when using multi modules only a single jar will
>   be produced and all the modules will be a part of that single jar.

This is true, in case of multi module gradle or maven project, each module is not a micro service and each module will have their respective maven pom.xml or build.gradle in case of Gradle. Each module will have their own jar files. In a typical microservice project, the modules can be resource layer which contains all resource end points, service layers, repository layer, entity layers etc. Each layer is considered as module. There will be a root project which will have parent pom.xml or build.gradle file based upon the application building tool. Besides in case of spring boot project, the parent project which contains all the modules will produce one fat jar which will have Boot-INF and inside it you will get module wise jar files along with other third party libraries.

If you are trying to convert a large monolithic application to microservice type, then first decide based upon reusable functionality which can be used in other microservices. I mean first one monolithic application will be converted to how many microservices. If you want to create a library like utility, then create a separate project and maintain it in Artifactory or Nexus and use as dependency in root/parent build.gradle file for the defined microservices.

You may also get other better opinions from others in this regard.

Comment: My goal was to manage dependencies and versions in a single location rather than 20 different microservices. Thoughts?

Comment: All the dependencies are maintained in a single location ie .gradle folder in the system. But each microservice will have its dependencies as part of spring boot. However if you want to club all the microservices, you can customize the gradle by writing groovy script.